# django filter on many to many along with Q

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-q

```
class ModelA:
    m2m1 = Foreignkey relatedname = 'm2ms'
```

We can get m2m1 objects using:

```
modela_instance.m2ms.all()
```

Sample output:

```
for x in ModelA.objects.all():
    print x.m2ms.all().values_list('id', Flat=True)

1,2,3
1,
[]
2
4,5
```

So, if I want fetch all instances whose m2ms has ids 1,2,3 (can have more too). Then I can do this:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(m2ms__id=1).filter(m2ms__id=2).filter(m2ms__id=3)
```

How can I do this with Q ?

```
ModelA.objects.filter(Q(some_boolean=True, simple_field=5) | Q(some_boolean=False, here m2ms should be 1,2,3 lets say))
```

From above requirement, I mean:

It should return records when (some_boolean=True, simple_field=5)  OR some_boolean=False, m2ms  should have 1,2,3(can have more).

Output:

```
If some_boolean=True, then we dont bother about m2ms. These records should have simple_field with value 5
If some_boolean=False, then for all records, each_record.m2ms.all().values_list('id', Flat=True) should contains 1,2,3. For example: 1)[1,2,3], 2)[1,2,3,4], 3)[1,2,3,5,6,7]
```

Please let me know for more clarification.

Comment: So just you know: English is not my first language but I'm under the impression that even a native speaker would have trouble to understand what you mean. Can you write the equivalent SQL query so we understand what you want?

Comment: @PauloScardine Updated english, please look again.