# django AND on Q not working for many to many

Tags: django, django-q

Here's the model:

```
class ModelA:
    title = charfield
    m2m = foreignkey, relatedname='m2ms'
```

This is working:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains='a') & Q(title__icontains='b'))
```

So it returns all records whose titles contains both letters 'a' and 'b'.

Then same not working for many to many:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(Q(m2ms__id=1) & Q(m2ms__id=2))
```

ModelA m2ms list:

```
for x in ModelA.objects.all():
    print x.m2ms.all().values_list('id', Flat=True)    

#Output:
1,2,3
1,2
1
1,3,5
4,6,7 
1,8
```

So, expected output of ModelA.objects.filter(Q(m2ms__id=1) & Q(m2ms__id=2))  should be records having these m2m ids: [1,2,3], [1,2].  But its not happening. Why ?

I cant use Q(m2ms__id__in=[1,2]) because it returns same even if I do __in=[1,2,3,4, infinite numbers]

Reason for using Q instead of filter is mentioned in this question - [django filter on many to many along with Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191563/django-filter-on-many-to-many-along-with-q)

Comment: Why not use `filter(Q(field=value), Q(field=value))` instead?

Comment: That is what the question is about. Its not working. ',' is equivalent to '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Read this section of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

Particularly this paragraph:

> To handle both of these situations, Django has a consistent way of processing filter() and exclude() calls. Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.

I believe if you do `ModelA.objects.filter(Q(m2ms__id__in=[1, 2]))` or `ModelA.objects.filter(m2ms__id__in=[1, 2])` it will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Syntax error - keyword argument repeated - ModelA.objects.filter(Q(m2ms__id=1, m2ms__id=2))

Comment: Updated answer to use ```__in```