# Django filter by many-to-many field doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

There is a model of Article and it has many-to-many categories field. I want to filter it by that field but it doesn't work as i expected. For example:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(categories__id__in = [0, 1, 2])
```

it gets model with categories 0 and 1 even if it hasn't category with id 2.
i tried something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(categories__id = 0) & Q(categories__id = 1) & Q(categories__id = 2))
```

but it even doesn't work. it doesn't even gets model if it has all of this categories.

By the way, **i don't want to use more than 1 filter method**

So, is there any solution for me?

Thanks.

P.S: [django AND on Q not working for many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193407/django-and-on-q-not-working-for-many-to-many) - the same question but author still doesn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can count if it matches three `Category`s and thus only retrieve items where the three match:

```
from django.db.models import Count

MyModel.objects.filter(
    categories__id__in=[0, 1, 2]
).annotate(
    category_count=Count('categories')
).filter(category_count=3)
```

Comment: but is there a way to solve the problem using only one filter method?

Comment: I use special class to generate parametres for filter method. I can make any queries but only inside one filter method

Comment: @greg: no, Django's filter works as an *existential quantifier*, not as a *universal quantifier*.